# Confusion in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

I'm beginner in Java, I'm trying to compile some small program, can somebody explain me, what is my problem, thanks in advance:

```
public abstract class SumFunction<Y,X> {
public abstract Y op (Y y, X x);
}

public class sumStringToInt  extends SumFunction{
        public int op(int num, String s){
            return s.length() + num;
        }
}
```

#### errors

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type sumStringToInt must implement the inherited abstract method SumFunction.op(Object, 
     Object)
    - SumFunction is a raw type. References to generic type SumFunction<Y,X> should be 
     parameterized
```

#### edited

is it possible in Java inherit without instantiaion of Base class?, thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are indicating that `SumFunction<Y,X>` is taking two arguments.

Thus your class should look like this:

```
public class sumStringToInt extends SumFunction<Integer,String> {
    public Integer op(Integer num, String s){
        return s.length() + num;
    }
}
```

Try that...

Answer (score 4):

Should be

```
public class sumStringToInt extends SumFunction<Integer,String>{
        public Integer op(Integer num, String s){
            return s.length() + num;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the type parameters when extending `SumFucntion`. `sumStringToInt` needs to extend `SumFunction<Integer,String>`.

Also, you can't use primitives in generics. So, use `Integer` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class sumStringToInt extends SumFunction<Integer, String>
{
    @Override
    public Integer op(int num, String s)
    {
        return s.length() + num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the type parameters for SumFunction. Because of that the compiler assumes you want to use the `raw type` which means `Y` and `X` use `Object` as their type.

```
public class sumStringToInt  extends SumFunction{
        public int op(int num, String s){
            return s.length() + num;
        }
}
```

If you pass the types you want to use for SumFunction, this should compile. Like so:

```
public class sumStringToInt extends SumFunction<Integer, String> {
        public int op(int num, String s){
            return s.length() + num;
        }
}
```

You may have noticed that we use `Integer` instead of `int` as the type. This is because you cannot use primitive types with generics. Luckily, there are wrapper Objects for each primitive type, in this case `Integer` for `int`.